# Websphere can't find my tag lib descriptor at runtime (occurs infrequently)

Tags: java, jsf, websphere

I am using RAD 8.0 and Websphere portal 6.1.0.3. I have developed my own JSF components.
I added all the things as per this tutorial:
[JSF Tag Tutorial](http://www.google.si/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://www.servogrid.org/slide/iSERVO/NMI/JSF/JSF%2520Custom%2520Tags.ppt&ei=CutyT_emE6So4gTN7v2NDw&usg=AFQjCNHvW16I6ei9KMLQOyGlkyIU9S54bA&sig2=uelgZ_wnEtomJ32YDgiwkQ)

And it worked. However suddenly I started getting a long stacktrace with

HTTP Error 500: Unable to locate tag library for uri /WEB-INF/tld/errors.tld,

when I open the page (errors.tld being my lib). Compile-time it doesn't complain about anything, in fact if I control+left click taglib directive in JSF file, it opens up the correct TLD file. Sometimes after clearing various temporary folders and recompiling the project I can get it to work again, but it will break again a few compiles and publishes to the server later (even though the only thing changed was some utility java class for instance). It has no rhyme or reason. Does anyone have this same problem and solution or workaround?

Comment: Apparently the problem can be resolved by inserting a space in the `<%@taglib` directive `uri` attribute, saving the file, then deleting the space, saving the file, compiling, and deploying. And then you have to do this for every directive in every JSF file that gives you problems. Which is one file every few compiles. So the problem is in RAD IDE. Any clues how to fix it, since this whack-a-mole with these senseless errors is costing a lot of time?